# VBA , Match and copy data using Find. got stuck in Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

[image]

I Have attached an image showing my data and what i want to achieve.

My code is not working properly . it copies data for 14 and bb1 and after that it gets stuck in the loop. Please help me to correct.

Why i want to use find method is , in H row for ex , i will have around 20 to 30 ids to match in 1000 rows ..so looping a whole row will take long time .

any idea how to correct and optimize the code. thanks

```
Sub Findandcopy()

    Dim shtOld As Worksheet, shtNew As Worksheet
    Dim oldRow As Integer
    Dim newRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, id, f As Range
    Dim g As Range
    Dim currow As Long

    Set shtOld = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")


With shtOld.Range("H1:H30")
    Set c = .find("*")

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address

        Do


            Set f = shtNew.Range("G2:G40").find(c)

            If Not f Is Nothing Then

                    currow = f.Cells.Row
                    shtNew.Activate
                    Set g = shtNew.Range("G" & currow).Resize(4, 2)
                    g.Copy
                    shtOld.Activate
                    shtOld.Range("I" & c.Row).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste

            End If



            Set c = .FindNext("*")

            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress

    End If
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with....  I didn't use Find and replace, just simply looped through the values in the two source sheets. I've commented the code so it should be reasonably easy to see what it's doing.

I've tested it and it worked on some data I replicated from the screenprints you provided.

---

```
Sub Findandcopy()

Dim sourceSht1 As Worksheet _
, sourceSht2 As Worksheet _
, destinationSht As Worksheet

Dim sourceValue As String
Dim endRow As Long

Dim counter As Integer

Set sourceSht1 = Sheet1
Set sourceSht2 = Sheet2
Set destinationSht = Sheet3

On Error GoTo Err

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


'get the end row of sourceSht2 (column H)
endRow = sourceSht2.Range("H" & sourceSht2.UsedRange.Count + 1).End(xlUp).Row


    'loop backwards as the sourceSht1 value that we want to get is after the beginning
    For i = endRow To 1 Step -1

    counter = counter + 1

    'get value from sourceSht 1
    If sourceSht1.Cells(i, 8).Value <> "" Then _
    sourceval = sourceSht1.Cells(i, 8).Value

    'we always copy the number from sourceSht2
    destinationSht.Cells(i, 10).Value = sourceSht2.Cells(i, 8).Value

            'if the counter is 4 then we've reached the top of the list
            If counter = 4 Then

            'value in column G is always at the top of the section (sourceSht2)
            destinationSht.Cells(i, 9).Value = sourceSht2.Cells(i, 8).Value

            'copy the value we stored from sourceSht1 (set number format to text)
            destinationSht.Cells(i, 8).NumberFormat = "@"
            destinationSht.Cells(i, 8).Value = sourceval


            'reset sourceval in case next section doesn't have any value in column H
            sourceval = ""

            'reset counter
            counter = 0

            End If
    Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


Exit Sub

Err:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I want to make my code faster .with your code ..it will loop for the whole row ..if i use find it will loop 20 or 30 times for 1000 rows. this is just an example in reality my data size is larger.

Comment: Did you test it? How long did it take? I think that this solution should be significantly faster than the code you posted.